# P4 - rollback to previous revision for files in a folder if revision is different for all files

Tags: perforce, rollback

How to rollback to previous revision for files in a folder together if revision of all the files is different using command line?
I have a requirement to rollback all the files inside a folder which also contains a sub folder and the revision of all files is not same. All the solutions that i have found requires revision number for the files. So the basic procedure is

To back out changelist 1000:

1. p4 sync @999
2. p4 edit //depot/foo.txt //depot/bar.txt //depot/ola.txt
3. p4 sync
4. p4 resolve -ay
5. p4 submit

As found here-
https://community.perforce.com/s/article/3474

the other option is to use *p4 undo* command but with this the whole CL is reverted which also reverts changes which are required in my case.

This can be achieved from GUI but what are the steps to achieve the same from command line or the only option is to revert all the files one by one?

Comment: Are you trying to figure out how to use a **file pattern** in step (2) rather than a single file **name**?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `p4 undo` command.

```
p4 undo folder/...@1000,now
```

will undo changelist 1000 and all the changelists after it.  (This is the equivalent of the steps you posted -- it doesn't only roll back changelist 1000 for those files, because you synced to head in step 3!)

```
p4 undo @1000,@1000
```

will undo changelist 1000 by itself.

(This also works with date ranges etc.)

Comment: @sam-stafford- can you give example for the undo for date range? Using above mentioned command worked for me, want to know how the same can be used with date.

Comment: canonical example: undo April Fool's jokes.  `p4 undo @2016/04/01,@2016/04/02` Dates are just a generic type of revision specifier in Perforce along with revision numbers, changelists, labels, client have lists...